# Removing shadows in a white background photo

Tags: gimp, background

How do I remove the shadow in this photo?

I tried fuzzy select on my actual image, the object has grey elements that make it difficult to distinguish properly. I can do by parts, but the real background also is grained due to the photo quality, and I don't know what operation to use to impose similar grain on the removed region.

[image: http://gimpchat.com/files/53_oranges_roba.png]

Answer (score 5):

You could use the `path tool` to go around the shadow area, convert the path to a selection and fill it with white.

Answer (score 3):

Really, all you can do is zoom in and use a brush on a mask. There's not any automated method I've found, in any application, which will do an adequate job. You need to do it manually.

Comment: For a cleaner edge, you might be better off using a vector mask in this case. It may also be quicker as it is a very strong shape and edge.

Answer (score 1):

The jpeg compression makes this image tricky to deal with using channel selections or color range. Although the blue channel is quite promising, the shadows close to the fruit are too close in tonal range to make that a useful option.

When you're making a selection to isolate part of an image, the image itself gives you the clue to what will be the best method. In this case, the edges are very smooth, clean and well defined. The best method would be to use the Path tool to outline the fruit and leaves, then turn that into a selection.

Photoshop has a selection tool that works very well in this instance because of the clearly-defined edges of the image, the Magnetic Lasso Tool, which lives under the regular Lasso Tool. In theory, the Gimp's "intelligent" Scissors Selection tool should do the same thing, but it doesn't quite have the smarts to make an accurate edge selection.

The Fuzzy selection tool works reasonably well if you turn on Add mode, set the threshold to around 25 and work carefully. Clean up using the Lasso tool in Subtract mode.

Comment: So good to see you back, Alan!

Answer (score 1):

Hope I'm not late for the question. I usually used https://www.fotor.com/features/background-remover to help remove background. So I try it this time too. First open and upload the picture, and then waiting for the tool has an auto background remover, and then retain and erase manually (thx god I only spend 1 minute to roughly remove the shadow). And finally, change into a white background again. The outcome is below, not a bad work, right? You can do it more carefully. Maybe it's time for these tools to create an auto function for removing the shadow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image is not a JPG, it seems to have the shadows as partially transparent grey and other parts of the background are fully transparent:

[image]

With separate white background layer the shadows can be seen clearly:

[image]

Select the image layer and adjust the alpha in Color > Curves. The next curve makes the shadows fully transparent:

[image]

The coarse selection (by lasso) covers the problematic shadows, but leaves out the no-shadow edges of the fruits and leaves. The idea is to avoid slicing off the 1...2 px wide partially transparent antialias-zone at the no-shadow edges.

In case the image really had a solid white background I would try at first GIMP's foreground-background selection tool which tries to find the edge between separately shown (=painted) foreground and background areas. In case the result with it was too coarse, I would bite the bullet and draw  a path around the fruits and leaves, convert it to a selection and cut the fruits and leaves to a new layer. In images this simple drawing a path is not a major task except in case one has tens or a hundred of them waiting.

Comment: Image is in fact a PNG

Answer (score -1):

To remove background from this image, you can try to use PhotoScissors, here is tutorial: http://www.photoscissors.com/how-to-remove-background-from-photo.html

Comment: Hi Max, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. Could you please tell us a bit more about what we can find at the link and how it helps in answering the question? That way, your answer is still valuable in case the link breaks at a later time. Thanks!

Comment: Remembering that although the question if for "GIMP" not "Photoshop" - GIMP also features a Scissors tool, so the tutorial might help.